# AS 3.0 Dynamic Instance Names

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, instances

Hi i made a custom class where i would like to create x instances of a movieclip. But the following doesn't work:

`package  {`

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class CustomClass extends MovieClip {

    public function CustomClass(amount:uint) {  
        var Collector:Array = new Array(); 

        //Add and position Tiles to stage.
        for (var i:uint = 1; i <= amount; i++){ 
            var newMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
            newMovieClip.y = amount * 10;
            Collector.push(newMovieClip); 
        }
        addChild(Collector);
    }
}
```

}

I would like to position them on the timeline with

```
var customClass_mc:CustomClass = new CustomClass(10);
addChild(customClass_mc);

//try to trace the x position of one of the instances. 
trace(customClass_mc.Collector[5].x);
```

I keep getting the error: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 5 1119: Access of possibly undefined property Collector through a reference with static type CustomClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another answer myself which i think is even better!

You don't need the container at all.

when you use the following

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class CustomClass extends MovieClip {

        public function CustomClass(amount:uint) {  

            //Add and position Tiles to stage.
            for (var i:uint = 1; i <= amount; i++){ 
                var newMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
                newMovieClip.y = amount * 10;
                newMovieClip.name = "clip"+i;
                addChild(newMovieClip); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No i can acces the movieclips by using:

```
var customClass_mc:CustomClass = new CustomClass(10);
addChild(customClass_mc);

//try to trace the x position of the fifth instance. 
trace(customClass_mc.getChildByName("child5").y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to declare Collector as public:

```
public var Collector:Array = new Array();
```

Your Collector is an array, not a display object, and so it can't be added to the display tree. Instead you would push each newMovieClip onto the display of Custom class and position them inside your for loop.  Then you don't need the collector at all, because you can target the movieclips using `getChildAt()`:

```
trace(customClass_mc.getChildAt(5).x);
```

Comment: Fantastic, the getChildAt method works! Besides that, making the Collector public gives me: 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package. Good thing is i don't need it anymore!

Comment: Sorry, I missed a bit of explanation there. To access the Collector from outside of the class constructor like you did in the last line of your example you would have to make it a class property. To do that you move it outside of the constructor function and add the `public` keyword.

Comment: Hey shanethehat, i found another way (i added an answer too). Do you agree that it is even easier to use?

Comment: Yes absolutely, your way is cleaner and easier if you've decided that the array is not required for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'Collector' is only available inside the constructor the way you have it.  Collector has to be made public to be accessible from outside the timeline.  The best thing to do would be to make a public getter method to access this.  So something like:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class CustomClass extends MovieClip {

    private var Collector:Array = new Array(); 

    public function get Collector():Array
    {
        return Collector;
    }

    public function CustomClass(amount:uint) {  

        //Add and position Tiles to stage.
        for (var i:uint = 1; i <= amount; i++){ 
            var newMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
            newMovieClip.y = amount * 10;
            Collector.push(newMovieClip); 
        }
        addChild(Collector);
    }
}
```

Comment: shanethehat's anwser worked, with yours i get 2 errors: 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject. & 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.

Thanks anyway